# How can I find the nearest integer to x that is divisible by y?

Tags: python-3.x

Create a NearestInteger function that accepts integer (x) and integer (y) input. This function will search for the number closest to x and divisible by y. If x is directly divisible by y, then outputs x only.

Example:

Input: n = 17, m = 4
Output: 16

Input: n = 18, m = 6
Output: 18

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Perhaps it would help if you included the code that you're working on.  SO isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function:

```
def nearest(n, x):
  u = n % x > x // 2
  return n + (-1)**(1 - u) * abs(x * u - n % x)

nearest(22, 6) #->24
nearest(24, 6) #->24
nearest(26, 6) #->24
nearest(26.999, 6) #->24.0
nearest(27, 6) #-> 24
nearest(27.00001, 6) #-> 30.0
nearest(29, 6) #->30
nearest(32, 6) #->30
```